# MYSQL: Create list of distinct column value per record

Tags: mysql, string-concatenation, distinct-values

```
Ticket_Number    Entered_By    Responded_By    Closed_By    Touched_by
----------------------------------------------------------------------
10001            John          NULL            Mike         John, Mike
10002            Sally         Mike            Mike         Sally, Mike
10003            NULL          George          Amber        George, Amber
10004            John          Holly           Timothy      John, Holly, Timothy
```

My data looks like the above.  What I am looking to do is add the last column, Touched_By.  Essentially I know I need to concatenate, remove the duplicates and then build a list without duplicated separators.  I just don't really know how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try this? you can test here http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7a4d2/1

```
SELECT number, GROUP_CONCAT(by_whom)
FROM (
    SELECT number, entered_by AS by_whom FROM ticket
    UNION
    SELECT number, responsed_by AS by_whom FROM ticket
    UNION
    SELECT number, closed_by AS by_whom FROM ticket
) x
WHERE by_whom IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY number;

+--------+-----------------------+
| number | GROUP_CONCAT(by_whom) |
+--------+-----------------------+
|  10001 | Mike,John             |
|  10002 | Mike,Sally            |
|  10003 | Amber,George          |
|  10004 | John,Timothy,Holly    |
+--------+-----------------------+
```

Please note that there is max length of `GROUP_CONCAT()` return value. Default value is enough for you which is 102400.

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'group_concat_max_len';
+----------------------+--------+
| Variable_name        | Value  |
+----------------------+--------+
| group_concat_max_len | 102400 |
+----------------------+--------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for!  What I actually used (adding some cleanup) below.

`SELECT ticket_number, REPLACE(trim(BOTH ',' from GROUP_CONCAT(by_whom)),',,',',')
FROM (
    SELECT ticket_number, entered_by AS by_whom FROM t_parature_ticket_details
    UNION
    SELECT ticket_number, initial_responder AS by_whom FROM t_parature_ticket_details
    UNION
    SELECT ticket_number, closed_by AS by_whom FROM t_parature_ticket_details
) x
WHERE by_whom IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY ticket_number LIMIT 1000;`

Answer (score 0):

The function `concat_ws()` has the nice feature that it skips `NULL` arguments.  That makes it useful for this:

```
select t.*,
       concat_ws(', ', Entered_By,
                 (case when Responded_By = Entered_By
                       then NULL else Responded_By
                  end),
                 (case when Closed_By = Entered_By or Closed_By = Responded_By
                       then NULL else Closed_By
                  end)
                ) as Resolved_By
```

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/30418) is a SQL Fiddle.